# Difficulty Embedding Fonts in PowerPoint Slides via insertSlidesFromBase64 Method

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I'm encountering an issue with the `insertSlidesFromBase64` method in PowerPoint. When I insert slides using this method, the embedded fonts in the slides are not being carried over. Specifically, I'm looking to ensure that the embedded font is applied correctly when inserting slides from base64.

The font I'm trying to embed is Arimo. I've confirmed that it's properly embedded in the original slide, but it doesn't seem to carry over when inserted using insertSlidesFromBase64.